# Praat scripting: Extracting syllable tier together with accent tier with extra changes

Tags: praat

I want to extract syllables together with the corresponding accents. If a syllable doesn't have an accent, there will be "no" on the accent part.

My coding example looks like this:

```
writeInfo: ""

selectObject: "TextGrid example"

# syllable tier is 1
# accent tier is 2
number = Get number of intervals: 1
for i from 1 to number
syllable$ = Get label of intervals: 1, i 
# It seems to be not possible to get time of interval
# I want to get the time of the whole interval, like it's done with points
syllable_time = Get time of interval: 1, i
accent = Get point at time: 2, syllable_time
accent$ = Get label of point: 2, accent
    #if no accent$
    #appendInfoLine syllable$, "      ", "no"
    #elif accent$ <> "-" and accent$ <> "%"
    #appendInfoLine syllable$, "      ", accent$
    #endif
endfor
```

The result should look like this:

```
"de:6       no
I           no
"Ra:n       H*L
"vIl        no
"an         no
"zaI        no
n@m         no
a:          no
"tOm        H*
```

**Adding**

Layers 1 and 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in a few steps. First, add an additional `'no'` to layer 2:

```
#Select TexGrid
selectObject: 1

number = Get number of intervals: 1

for i from 1 to number
time_start = Get start point: 1, i
#time_end = Get end point: 1, i
name$ = Get label of interval: 1, i
point$ = Get label of point: 2, i

Insert point: 2, time_start, "no"
endfor
```

Then, extract the information from layer 2 and save it to a file:

```
#Select TextGrid
selectObject: 1

number = Get number of points: 2
for n from 1 to number
accent_time = Get time of point: 2, n
syllable = Get interval at time: 1, accent_time 
syllable$ = Get label of interval: 1, syllable
accent$ = Get label of point: 2, n

writeFileLine: "myFile.txt", accent$

endfor
```

As the last step, you need to remove those additional `'no'`'s from your outcome. Let's do that in Python (Mention all the pitch shapes you have, so the program knows what lines you want to get rid of):

```
fo = open("myFile.txt", "r")
st = fo.read();
lis = st.split()
fo.close()


for i, choice in enumerate(lis):
    if choice == 'H*L' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'H*' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'L*H' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'L%' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'H%' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'L*' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == '!H*L' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == '!H*' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'H*L?' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == '..L' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'L*HL' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == '*?' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'L*H?' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'H*?' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == '..H' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'L*?' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == '!H' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'H!' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'HH*L' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == '!H*L?' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == '.L' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'L*!H' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'L*HL?' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)
    elif choice == 'LH*L' and lis[i-1] == 'no':
        lis.pop(i-1)


with open("output.txt", "w") as my_file:
    for i in lis:
        my_file.write(i + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, did it as an interval tier for tier2 before. Now as point tier:

```
objName$ = selected$ ("Sound")
select TextGrid 'objName$'

intervals_1 = Get number of intervals: 1
intervals_2 = Get number of points: 2

for i from 1 to intervals_1
 syl_1$ = Get label of interval: 1, i
 start_1 = Get start point: 1, i
 end_1 = Get end point: 1, i
 for j from 1 to intervals_2
  syl_2$ = Get label of point: 2, j
  time = Get time of point: 2, j
  if syl_1$ != "" and syl_2$ != "" and time > start_1 and time < end_1
   printline 'syl_1$' 'syl_2$'
  endif
 endfor
endfor
```

Comment: It works if the boundaries of the layers collide. I'm going to add the picture of my layers in the post.

Comment: Oh, somehow I didn't get a notification about your edit. As you can tell, my tier 2 is a point tier, not an interval tier like on your picture. So, your script gives an error.

Comment: @dgr379 - d'oh I missed that, then it's even simpler logic, I'll edit again.

Comment: You forgot to do something like this: `time > start_1 and time < end_1`

`Insert point: 2, time, "no"` before extracting labels of point tier 2.